# JSF explicit navigation

Tags: jsf, navigation

I have AddUser.xhtml and it has a form.On submit of the form the target xhtml is ListUser.xhtml. I am able to navigate from source to target xhtml. However the URL is not changing since JSF supports implicit navigation.

Can i somehow make the URL change on succcessful form submit ?
Eg:
From :http://:8080/jsf/AddUser.xhtml
To:   http://:8080/jsf/ListUser.xhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to redirect the page to get the URL to change. In the URL that you are returning on submit, append the following.

```
http://:8080/jsf/ListUser.xhtml>faces-redirect=true
```

Comment: Shouldn't this param and value needs to be appended to AddUser.xhtml ? I did the same in the bean User.java.I have a submit method which is the action of AddUser.xhtml. Inside the submit method i have " return "/ListUser.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";". Should this be sufficient ?

Comment: Yes. You invoke the method from AddUser.xhtml and that method returns the next view name as a String. In your case you need to return the next view name appended with the faces-redirect=true. i.e. The method should return ListUser.xhtml?faces-redirect=true (assuming both xhtmls are in the same directory).

Comment: Yeah... But the target URL is still not changing.It still displays the response content in the same page. i.e, AddUser.xhtml. The PRG pattern also defines the same way. But nothing works !

Comment: Can you post your AddUser.xhtml and the invoked method please.

Comment: public class UserBean {
  private int id;
     private String name;
     private List<Item> items;
      
     private String password;
     private String comments;
     
  //Action method to add user
     public String addUser() {
          
         return "/ListUser.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
     }   
   
}

Comment: Unable to post AddUser.xhtml.Its too long it says

Comment: <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>AddUser</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/AddUser.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
           <!--  <from-outcome>success</from-outcome> -->
            <to-view-id>/ListUser.xhtml</to-view-id>
           <!--  <redirect /> -->
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

Comment: <h:form id="myform">
   <h:panelGrid border="1" columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="ID"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText id="User_ID" value="#{userBean.id}" required="true">
     <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="500" />
    </h:inputText>
    
    <h:commandButton id="Submit" action="#{userBean.addUser}" value="Add Customer">
    </h:commandButton>
   </h:panelGrid>
              
 </h:form>

Comment: There you are.Posted only form having one field and a submit

Comment: What version of jsf are you using ?

Comment: I am using version 2.0

Comment: Try removing the navigation case for the page then.

Comment: It says "Redirection is not allowed to the URL : /jsf/ListUser.xhtml. "

Comment: Hi... The above error was because of some framework that we are using.
After doing the above mentioned changes it works fine and the URL changes. 
Thanks Adarsh.